# For which values of $a$ is $e^{-a\sqrt x}$ convex in $\mathbb R^+$?

Tags: convex-analysis, exponential-function

I failed the following question in a quiz:

For which values of $a$ the function $e^{-a\sqrt x}$ with $dom  = \mathbb{R}^+$ is convex? Check all that apply:

1. $a\leq0$
2. $a\geq0$
3. $-1 \leq a\leq1$
4. $a\leq-1$

I said that in all cases it is convex because when plotting for me it was kind of obvious. However, the correct answer is 2. Why?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try taking the second derivative?  This will be nonnegative if the function is convex (concave up).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, why not to differentiate twice and check?

$$f(x):=e^{-a\sqrt x}\;,\;\;f'(x)=-\frac a{2\sqrt x}e^{-a\sqrt x}\;,$$

$$f''(x)=\frac{e^{-a\sqrt x}}{4x}a\left(\frac 1{\sqrt x}+a\right)$$

Now

$$f''(x) \geq 0\iff a\left(\frac1{\sqrt x}+a\right) \geq 0\iff\begin{cases} a \geq 0\;,\;\;\;\text{or}
\\{}\\a<0\;\;\text{and}\;\;\frac1{\sqrt x}<-a\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you for that, but why I cannot see that when plotting? I am trying to figure out a value of a for which the second derivative is negative, but I am not able to find it to plot it.

Comment: Well @JaviV , according to the above the second derivative is negative if for example $$\;a=-1\;\;\text{and}\;\;\frac1{\sqrt x}<1\iff \;a=-1\;\;\text{and}\;\;\sqrt x>1\;$$

Comment: Wow thank you. That helped me to visualize that it actually non-convex.